# Will I be at any advantage turning in my resume during Christmas?

Tags: resume, applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is December a bad time to submit a job application?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-december-a-bad-time-to-submit-a-job-application)

As everyone knows tomorrow is Christmas, since everyone else is with their families showing Christmas cheer tomorrow, if I turn in my resume during that day will my application show up at the top of the stack since nobody else is applying?

Comment: Most resumes are electronic and no longer 'stacked'

Comment: What are the differences between your question and http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-december-a-bad-time-to-submit-a-job-application ?

Comment: your resume will be OK only if you put it under recruiter's Christmas tree