# Does applying for jobs over Christmas break look bad?

Tags: job-search

This question is similar to [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/is-december-a-bad-time-to-submit-a-job-application), but not quite the same. That question asks if it's inconvenient for them to receive applications in December.

My question is - if I'm applying for jobs over Christmas because I have the free time - does that look unattractive in the eyes of an employer?

Comment: If that's the only time you have 'free time' you must be busy - employers would consider that a good sign.  Someone on LinkedIn posted an article about a 'hiring frenzy' in January, so that would suggest having a resume sitting in someone's inbox right now is particularly good timing.

Comment: I second @MeredithPoor. The fact that you're looking for a job at this time of the year (when nobody else bothers) is a good sign. It shows you're willing to work (or desperate for money...)

Comment: No it doesn't - every company I've ever worked for has had a big hiring push in January so having your application in December certainly won't hurt. There is a chance there will be a significant "hold" period before they get round to processing it though which probably isn't ideal if your only time off is in December.

Answer (score 3):

My company are still interviewing at this point and we're still more than happy to receive applications.  Interviews are also alot easier to arrange at this time of year, no messing around because applicants have much more free time.

I see no reason why this would be inconvenient for the employer.  I don't imagine anyone would judge you for it either, I can't think of a good reason to.   In fact it may show you in a positive light as there is more chance you have waited till you have free time yourself when you applied.  So it -to me- would show that you have been too focused on your current position to apply for others until now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing jobs being advertised in newspapers, company websites, and other locations then companies are looking. Yes some business and industries have slow periods for hiring; but many do not.

Some organizations also use the winter months to prepare for hiring college students in the summer for paid or unpaid internships. If you wait till the spring you may be too late.

Some companies plan hires in response to growing their business and may link it to their planning cycle. But that cycle can take place at any time during the calendar year. Others base their hiring on winning new contracts so they have no direct link to the calendar.